# List new offices created by year

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with a list of OfficeLicensePurchases.

In that list I need to count how many Offices were created in each year.

And I know that by the earliest license object.

Since the OfficeId is unique, if I have more than one license object for a Office, I just have to count the oldest one. That would mean the year when that Office was created in the database.

So I have:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "514de62f-0a4c-46c8-ba66-5692935f0930",
    "OfficeId": "09ac58f0-8d2a-42ec-ba47-f518dd9d0904",
    "PlanName": "Plan 50",
    "PlanPrice": 777,
    "PaidValue": 330,
    "CreationDate": {
      "$date": "2017-03-08T03:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "Status": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": "e41a5923-3a69-43bb-87a4-f1169e172e2e",
    "OfficeId": "9679fdf7-02a1-4a1f-b0f0-17d3505e86e3",
    "PlanName": "Plan 50",
    "PlanPrice": 777,
    "PaidValue": 330,
    "CreationDate": {
      "$date": "2019-03-08T03:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "Status": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": "d314a8bf-0147-4aee-8357-f36db686c85a",
    "OfficeId": "eab54926-0c11-4c9f-aee2-7fbeabad4135",
    "PlanName": "Plan 50",
    "PlanPrice": 777,
    "PaidValue": 330,
    "CreationDate": {
      "$date": "2021-03-08T03:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "Status": 2
  }
]
```

Expected Result:

```
[
 {CreationYear: 2018, NewOffices: 1},
 {CreationYear: 2019, NewOffices: 1},
 {CreationYear: 2021, NewOffices: 1}
]
```

Comment: Your data should be something like this: [Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EtFNgNcTG6Z). Since you are trying to group by `Year` and `OfficeId`, your expected data will be difficult to read if you are showing the `Year` value only, how would you know the particular data row is belonged to which `OfficeId`. And note that there is no `AccountingOfficeId` field in provided document.

Comment: Corrected the data.

The thing is, I need to count how many Offices were created in each year.

And I know that by the earliest license object. (in case of one Office has more than one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `$group` - Group by `OfficeId` and get the earliest `CreationDate`.
2. `$group` - Group by the `OfficeCreationDate`'s year and perform the count.
3. `$project` - Decorate output documents.
4. `$sort` (Optional) - Order the document by `CreationYear` ascending.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$OfficeId",
      OfficeCreationDate: {
        $min: "$CreationDate"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        $year: "$OfficeCreationDate"
      },
      NewOffice: {
        $count: {}
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      CreationYear: "$_id",
      NewOffice: "$NewOffice"
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      CreationYear: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KP8mPr3M9dH)